# Keda scaledobject can't see Prometheus metrics

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, autoscaling, horizontal-pod-autoscaling, keda

I am having trouble using a Keda scaledobject with a prometheus trigger. For some reason my Keda scaled object can't see prometheus metrics exposed from a .NET application which I want to use for horizontal pod autoscaling.

I'm not sure if it is because I have the incorrect prometheus server details in the scaled object or something more subtle is causing my issues.

In essesnce, the error I am seeing when i describe my horizontalpodautoscaler.autoscaling is:

```
  ScalingActive  False   FailedGetExternalMetric  the HPA was unable to compute the replica count: unable to get external metric default/s0-prometheus-hs_ready_readiness/&LabelSelector{MatchLabels:map[string]string{scaledobject.keda.sh/name: prometheus-scaledobject,},MatchExpressions:[]LabelSelectorRequirement{},}: unable to fetch metrics from external metrics API: Get "https://hcp-kubernetes.6416bc6ff2dbef0001660539.svc.cluster.local:443/apis/external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/default/s0-prometheus-hs_ready_readiness?labelSelector=scaledobject.keda.sh%!F(MISSING)name%!D(MISSING)prometheus-scaledobject": stream error: stream ID 29285; INTERNAL_ERROR; received from peer
```

Details are as follows:

Using Azure Kubernetes Service I have created a 3 node cluster.

```
kubectl get nodes -o wide

NAME                                STATUS   ROLES   AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION     CONTAINER-RUNTIME
aks-nodepool1-42472506-vmss00000l   Ready    agent   39m   v1.24.9   10.224.0.4    <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS   5.4.0-1104-azure   containerd://1.6.18+azure-1
aks-nodepool1-42472506-vmss00000m   Ready    agent   39m   v1.24.9   10.224.0.6    <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS   5.4.0-1104-azure   containerd://1.6.18+azure-1
aks-nodepool1-42472506-vmss00000n   Ready    agent   39m   v1.24.9   10.224.0.5    <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS   5.4.0-1104-azure   containerd://1.6.18+azure-1
```

Have a deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: servant-deploy
  labels:
    app: servant-app
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: servant-app
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: servant-app-volume
          configMap:
            name: servant-app
      containers:
      - name: servant-app
        image: scalingacr.azurecr.io/statelessservantservice_image
        volumeMounts:
          - name: servant-app-volume
            mountPath: /app/appsettings.k8s.json
            subPath: appsettings.k8s.json
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 500m
          requests:
            cpu: 200m
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: acr-secret
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: servant-app
```

With associated service.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: servant-service
  labels:
    app: servant-app
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: servant-app
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      name: web
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

```
kubectl apply -f deplyment.yaml
kubectl apply -f service.yaml
```

Have installed prometheus operator as follows:

```
git clone https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus.git
 
# Navigate to the kube-prometheus folder and run the commands (as detailed in https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus/tree/release-0.12):
kubectl apply --server-side -f manifests/setup
kubectl wait \
    --for condition=Established \
    --all CustomResourceDefinition \
    --namespace=monitoring
kubectl apply -f manifests/
```

Have created prometheus and an associated service monitor to allow prometheus to scrape metrics from my .NET application:

prometheus.yaml

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: Prometheus
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: prometheus
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: k8s
    app.kubernetes.io/name: prometheus
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: kube-prometheus
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 2.32.1
  name: applications
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  image: quay.io/prometheus/prometheus:v2.32.1
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/os: linux
  replicas: 1
  resources:
    requests:
      memory: 400Mi
  ruleSelector: {}
  securityContext:
    fsGroup: 2000
    runAsNonRoot: true
    runAsUser: 1000
  serviceAccountName: prometheus-k8s
  serviceMonitorNamespaceSelector: {} #match all namespaces
  #serviceMonitorNamespaceSelector:
  #  matchLabels:
  #    kubernetes.io/metadata.name: default
  serviceMonitorSelector: {} #match all servicemonitors
  version: v2.32.1
```

servicemonitor.yaml

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  labels:
  name: servant-app
  namespace: default
spec:
  endpoints:
  - interval: 30s
    port: web
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: servant-app
```

```
kubectl apply -f prometheus.yaml
kubectl apply -f servicemonitor.yaml

kubectl -n monitoring get svc

NAME                    TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
alertmanager-main       ClusterIP   10.0.29.217    <none>        9093/TCP,8080/TCP            34m
alertmanager-operated   ClusterIP   None           <none>        9093/TCP,9094/TCP,9094/UDP   34m
blackbox-exporter       ClusterIP   10.0.161.43    <none>        9115/TCP,19115/TCP           34m
grafana                 ClusterIP   10.0.66.180    <none>        3000/TCP                     34m
kube-state-metrics      ClusterIP   None           <none>        8443/TCP,9443/TCP            34m
node-exporter           ClusterIP   None           <none>        9100/TCP                     34m
prometheus-adapter      ClusterIP   10.0.120.223   <none>        443/TCP                      34m
prometheus-k8s          ClusterIP   10.0.167.102   <none>        9090/TCP,8080/TCP            34m
prometheus-operated     ClusterIP   None           <none>        9090/TCP                     34m
prometheus-operator     ClusterIP   None           <none>        8443/TCP                     34m
```

Can access prometheus UI using command:

```
kubectl -n monitoring port-forward service/prometheus-operated 9090:9090
```

Can see my .NET application metric hs_ready_readiness in prometheus.

Installed Keda as follows:

```
# Install helm 3
curl -fsSL -o get_helm.sh <address of helm 3>
chmod 700 get_helm.sh
./get_helm.sh
 
# Install Keda
helm repo add kedacore https://kedacore.github.io/charts
helm repo update
 
kubectl create namespace keda 
helm install keda kedacore/keda --namespace keda --set metricsServer.useHostNetwork=true --set prometheus.metricServer.enabled=true
```

```
kubectl -n keda get all

NAME                                                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/keda-admission-webhooks-6cd9cdbff8-mjr8r           1/1     Running   0          91m
pod/keda-operator-7d5994cbf9-bpqpv                     1/1     Running   0          91m
pod/keda-operator-metrics-apiserver-67879677bd-xhwp4   1/1     Running   0          91m

NAME                                      TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                   AGE
service/keda-admission-webhooks           ClusterIP   10.0.226.117   <none>        443/TCP                   3h46m
service/keda-operator                     ClusterIP   10.0.228.219   <none>        9666/TCP                  3h46m
service/keda-operator-metrics-apiserver   ClusterIP   10.0.87.217    <none>        443/TCP,80/TCP,9022/TCP   3h46m

NAME                                              READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/keda-admission-webhooks           1/1     1            1           3h46m
deployment.apps/keda-operator                     1/1     1            1           3h46m
deployment.apps/keda-operator-metrics-apiserver   1/1     1            1           3h46m

NAME                                                         DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/keda-admission-webhooks-6cd9cdbff8           1         1         1       3h46m
replicaset.apps/keda-operator-7d5994cbf9                     1         1         1       3h46m
replicaset.apps/keda-operator-metrics-apiserver-67879677bd   1         1         1       3h46m
```

With keda running I apply the following scaled object to get my metric hs_ready_readiness:

hs-keda3.yaml

```
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
  name: prometheus-scaledobject
  namespace: default
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    name: servant-deploy
  triggers:
  - type: prometheus
    metadata:
      serverAddress: http://prometheus-operated.monitoring.svc.cluster.local:80
      metricName: hs_ready_readiness
      threshold: '1'
      query: hs_ready_readiness
```

```
kubectl get all

NAME                                                                   REFERENCE                   TARGETS             MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
horizontalpodautoscaler.autoscaling/keda-hpa-prometheus-scaledobject   Deployment/servant-deploy   <unknown>/1 (avg)   1         100       1          3m23s
```

```
kubectl describe horizontalpodautoscaler.autoscaling/keda-hpa-prometheus-scaledobject

  Type           Status  Reason                   Message
  ----           ------  ------                   -------
  AbleToScale    True    SucceededGetScale        the HPA controller was able to get the target's current scale
  ScalingActive  False   FailedGetExternalMetric  the HPA was unable to compute the replica count: unable to get external metric default/s0-prometheus-hs_ready_readiness/&LabelSelector{MatchLabels:map[string]string{scaledobject.keda.sh/name: prometheus-scaledobject,},MatchExpressions:[]LabelSelectorRequirement{},}: unable to fetch metrics from external metrics API: Get "https://hcp-kubernetes.6416bc6ff2dbef0001660539.svc.cluster.local:443/apis/external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/default/s0-prometheus-hs_ready_readiness?labelSelector=scaledobject.keda.sh%!F(MISSING)name%!D(MISSING)prometheus-scaledobject": stream error: stream ID 29285; INTERNAL_ERROR; received from peer
Events:
  Type     Reason                        Age   From                       Message
  ----     ------                        ----  ----                       -------
  Warning  FailedGetExternalMetric       76s   horizontal-pod-autoscaler  unable to get external metric default/s0-prometheus-hs_ready_readiness/&LabelSelector{MatchLabels:map[string]string{scaledobject.keda.sh/name: prometheus-scaledobject,},MatchExpressions:[]LabelSelectorRequirement{},}: unable to fetch metrics from external metrics API: Get "https://hcp-kubernetes.6416bc6ff2dbef0001660539.svc.cluster.local:443/apis/external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/default/s0-prometheus-hs_ready_readiness?labelSelector=scaledobject.keda.sh%2Fname%3Dprometheus-scaledobject": stream error: stream ID 28963; INTERNAL_ERROR; received from peer
  Warning  FailedComputeMetricsReplicas  76s   horizontal-pod-autoscaler  invalid metrics (1 invalid out of 1), first error is: failed to get s0-prometheus-hs_ready_readiness external metric: unable to get external metric default/s0-prometheus-hs_ready_readiness/&LabelSelector{MatchLabels:map[string]string{scaledobject.keda.sh/name: prometheus-scaledobject,},MatchExpressions:[]LabelSelectorRequirement{},}: unable to fetch metrics from external metrics API: Get "https://hcp-kubernetes.6416bc6ff2dbef0001660539.svc.cluster.local:443/apis/external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/default/s0-prometheus-hs_ready_readiness?labelSelector=scaledobject.keda.sh%2Fname%3Dprometheus-scaledobject": stream error: stream ID 28963; INTERNAL_ERROR; received from peer
```

```
kubectl get apiservices

NAME                                   SERVICE                                AVAILABLE   AGE
v1.                                    Local                                  True        3d3h
v1.admissionregistration.k8s.io        Local                                  True        3d3h
v1.apiextensions.k8s.io                Local                                  True        3d3h
v1.apps                                Local                                  True        3d3h
v1.authentication.k8s.io               Local                                  True        3d3h
v1.authorization.k8s.io                Local                                  True        3d3h
v1.autoscaling                         Local                                  True        3d3h
v1.batch                               Local                                  True        3d3h
v1.certificates.k8s.io                 Local                                  True        3d3h
v1.coordination.k8s.io                 Local                                  True        3d3h
v1.discovery.k8s.io                    Local                                  True        3d3h
v1.events.k8s.io                       Local                                  True        3d3h
v1.monitoring.coreos.com               Local                                  True        36m
v1.networking.k8s.io                   Local                                  True        3d3h
v1.node.k8s.io                         Local                                  True        3d3h
v1.policy                              Local                                  True        3d3h
v1.rbac.authorization.k8s.io           Local                                  True        3d3h
v1.scheduling.k8s.io                   Local                                  True        3d3h
v1.snapshot.storage.k8s.io             Local                                  True        3h56m
v1.storage.k8s.io                      Local                                  True        3d3h
v1alpha1.keda.sh                       Local                                  True        94m
v1alpha1.monitoring.coreos.com         Local                                  True        36m
v1beta1.batch                          Local                                  True        3d3h
v1beta1.discovery.k8s.io               Local                                  True        3d3h
v1beta1.events.k8s.io                  Local                                  True        3d3h
v1beta1.external.metrics.k8s.io        keda/keda-operator-metrics-apiserver   True        3h48m
v1beta1.flowcontrol.apiserver.k8s.io   Local                                  True        3d3h
v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io                 kube-system/metrics-server             True        40m
v1beta1.node.k8s.io                    Local                                  True        3d3h
v1beta1.policy                         Local                                  True        3d3h
v1beta1.snapshot.storage.k8s.io        Local                                  True        3h56m
v1beta1.storage.k8s.io                 Local                                  True        3d3h
v1beta2.flowcontrol.apiserver.k8s.io   Local                                  True        3d3h
v2.autoscaling                         Local                                  True        3d3h
v2beta1.autoscaling                    Local                                  True        3d3h
v2beta2.autoscaling                    Local                                  True        3d3h
```

Any ideas why my Keda scaled object can't see my .NET application metric would be much appreaciated.